# Why do children of my popup panel appear outside of the panel

Tags: apache-flex, layout, flex4, air, popup

I am using the flex 4 popup manager to popup a panel, but the children of the panel are not staying inside the panel. But when i close the popup the children are being removed.

Like this: (sorry i can't post pics)

```
           ----------
           l________l
           l        l
  ..... please enterl
           l--------1
```

Anybody know why? Here's my code:

```
var forgotPopup:Panel = PopUpManager.createPopUp(this, forgottenForm, true) as Panel;
        PopUpManager.centerPopUp(forgotPopup);
```

And here's what i'm popping up:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Panel xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" width="218" height="168" skinClass="PanelSkin" title="Reset Details">


    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            import mx.controls.Alert;
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;
            import mx.managers.PopUpManager;

            // Handle the close button and Cancel button.
            private function handleCloseEvent():void {
                PopUpManager.removePopUp(this);
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <mx:Form horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0">
        <mx:FormHeading label="Please enter your e-mail address and your login details will be e-mailed to you"/>
        <mx:FormItem label="E-mail">
            <s:TextInput id="userInput" x="78" y="49"/>
        </mx:FormItem>
        <mx:FormItem direction="horizontal">
            <s:Button id="okButton" label="Submit" skinClass="ButtonSkin" />
            <s:Button id="cancelButton" label="Cancel" skinClass="ButtonSkin"/>
        </mx:FormItem>  
    </mx:Form>

</s:Panel>
```

Any help on this would be brilliant, thanks.

Comment: Why are you using MX forms and not Spark forms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Panel xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" width="218" height="168" skinClass="PanelSkin" title="Reset Details">


    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            import mx.controls.Alert;
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;
            import mx.managers.PopUpManager;

            // Handle the close button and Cancel button.
            private function handleCloseEvent():void {
                PopUpManager.removePopUp(this);
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <mx:Form left="10" right="10" top="10" bottom="10">
        <mx:FormHeading label="Please enter your e-mail address and your login details will be e-mailed to you"/>
        <mx:FormItem label="E-mail">
            <s:TextInput id="userInput" x="78" y="49"/>
        </mx:FormItem>
        <mx:FormItem direction="horizontal">
            <s:Button id="okButton" label="Submit" skinClass="ButtonSkin" />
            <s:Button id="cancelButton" label="Cancel" skinClass="ButtonSkin"/>
        </mx:FormItem>  
    </mx:Form>

</s:Panel>
```

If you need to have header word wrapped you should reject standard `FormHeading` and replace it with `Label`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Panel xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" width="218" height="168" skinClass="PanelSkin" title="Reset Details">


    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            import mx.controls.Alert;
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;
            import mx.managers.PopUpManager;

            // Handle the close button and Cancel button.
            private function handleCloseEvent():void {
                PopUpManager.removePopUp(this);
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <mx:Form left="10" right="10" top="10" bottom="10">
        <s:Label width="100%" text="Please enter your e-mail address and your login details will be e-mailed to you" fontWeight="bold" />
        <mx:FormItem label="E-mail">
            <s:TextInput id="userInput" x="78" y="49"/>
        </mx:FormItem>
        <mx:FormItem direction="horizontal">
            <s:Button id="okButton" label="Submit" skinClass="ButtonSkin" />
            <s:Button id="cancelButton" label="Cancel" skinClass="ButtonSkin"/>
        </mx:FormItem>  
    </mx:Form>

</s:Panel>
```

But the best way is to switch to [Spark `Form`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/Form.html) which is available since Flex 4.5.

Comment: Yeah that nearly worked but now just the heading is coming out of the right edge. I need the header to go on more than one line basically, is there a way to do this?

Thanks for fixing my dodgy diagram!

Comment: Thanks, i added a height = 100% too to make the label show all the text and that worked.

I have flash builder 4 premium but i have no clue how to upgrade the sdk or whether i have to buy 4.5!

Comment: I didn't try to use Flash Builder 4 with Flex SDK 4.5. But you can try to add SDK 4.5 through preferences (`Flash Builder > Installed Flex SDKs`) and switch your current project to it.

Answer (score 0):

Please Avoid X and Y position 
this might also cause the Objects Positions.

Comment: That wasn't the problem but you are correct and i have since removed those, thanks